# JMeter JSON parse

Tags: json, jmeter

Need help parsing JSON when the response data starts with extraneous chars.

I am able to extract data from the example using JSON extraction query - `$.results`

```
**Working example:** 
{
   "results" : [
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "2300",
               "short_name" : "2300",
               "types" : [ "street_number" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "22201",
               "short_name" : "22201",
               "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

However, I am unable to find any suitable methods to extract data from the following JSON object:

```
/**/_xdc_._9l6mlb && _xdc_._9l6mlb( {
   "results" : [
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "2300",
               "short_name" : "2300",
               "types" : [ "street_number" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "22201",
               "short_name" : "22201",
               "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
)
```

Tried using wildcard to escape the leading chars before JSON object with - `*$.results` - but no luck

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: have 2 post-processors: one removes "the garbage", second extracts json from cleaned data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This `/**/_xdc_._9l6mlb && _xdc_._9l6mlb(` bit makes your JSON a little bit invalid. I would suggest using [JSR223 PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) and [Groovy](http://www.groovy-lang.org/) language instead like:

```
import groovy.json.JsonBuilder
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

def response = prev.getResponseDataAsString()

def cleanResponse = response.substring(response.indexOf("{"), response.lastIndexOf(")"))
def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper()
def json = jsonSlurper.parseText(cleanResponse)
def results = json.results

def builder = new JsonBuilder(results)

vars.put("results", builder.toPrettyString())
```

The above code will do absolutely the same as JSON Path PostProcessor and store the value into `${results}` JMeter Variable

References:

- [Parsing and producing JSON](http://groovy-lang.org/json.html)
- [Beanshell vs JSR223 vs Java JMeter Scripting: The Performance-Off You've Been Waiting For!](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/beanshell-vs-jsr223-vs-java-jmeter-scripting-its-performance)

Comment: Thanks Dmitri. I also found another way to resolved this issue: use 'Regular Expression Extractor' to strip the extraneous chars and save JSON into a variable. Dump this variable as an output using a Dummy sampler and then parse the resulting JSON