# Extract JSON value based on condition using Jmeter from an HTML page

Tags: jmeter

I want to extract JSON value based on condition using jmeter from an HTML page.

```
<!doctype html>
var list_data_obj = [{
   "list": [
     {
       "field1": "123",
       "field2": "xyz"
     },
     {
       "field1": "456",
       "field2": "abc"
     },
     {
       "field1": "789",
       "field2": "asdf"
     }
   ],
       "other1": "qwerty",
       "other2": "asdfgh"
 }]
</html>
```

have tried JSON Path Extractor as below but returned `NULL`.

```
$.list[?(@.field2 == 'abc')].field1
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to use JSON Path Extractor as response data is **not a valid JSON**, it looks like a mix of HTML and JavaScript therefore you will need to use [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) instead.

The relevant Regular Expression will look like:

```
"field1": "(.+?)",\s.*"field2": "abc"
```

[image: JMeter Regular Expression Extractor]

References:

- [JMeter: Regular Expressions](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html)
- [Using RegEx (Regular Expression Extractor) With JMeter](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421325-Using-RegEx-Regular-Expression-Extractor-with-JMeter)
- [Perl 5 Regex Cheat sheet](https://perlmaven.com/regex-cheat-sheet)

Answer (score 0):

The key is to first extract a valid json using a regular expression, then apply a json path extractor on the previously extracted json.

You can perform a **2-step extraction** to do this:

- First Extract the Json from the page by performing a regexp extractor with `"list": ([^^]+}\])`, group `$1$`,
- Then perform a Json Extractor on the extracted variable by selecting `JMeter variable`, then apply your json path `$.list[?(@.field2 == 'abc')].field1`.

Useful resources:

- [How to extract data from Json with JMeter](https://octoperf.com/blog/2017/03/09/how-to-extract-data-from-json-response-using-jmeter/)

Comment: Another user chose the same solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39238561/jmeter-json-parse

Comment: How can I perform the second step? if I use the json Extractor under same HTTP request where regEx applied, then JSON extractor returns NULL.

Comment: The json extractor must be applied on the JMeter variable extracted from the previous regexp extractor. It's the only way to chain them.